# Default laravel notification --> data is not working

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm trying to use default Laravel notification, but i don't understand why  it's not showing the data.

This is my code

`/notification/NewReply.php`

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class NewReply extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $user;
    public $association;
    public $opportunity;

    public function __construct($user, $association, $opportunity)
    {
      $this->user = $user;
      $this->opportunity = $opportunity;
      $this->association = $association;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
          'user_id' => $this->user->id,
          'association_name' => $this->association->association_name,
          'opportunity_id' => $this->opportunity->id,
          'opportunity_name' => $this->opportunity->title,
        ];
    }
}
```

This is how i trigger the notification

```
$company->notify(new NewReply(Auth::user(),$association,$opportunity));
```

This is the data field saved after triggering, that is correct

```
{"user_id":2,"association_name":"Super delter","opportunity_id":1,"opportunity_name":"Afro tenders"}
```

i'll echo like this, as the documentation

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
<p>{{$notification->data['association_name']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

But i get nothing... anyone have an idea?

Comment: You are notifying the $company, try notifying directly on the user

Comment: Also make sure you are uisng `Notifiable Trait` in User model.